# Why does the wifi icon in my systray look like this?

Tags: windows-7, notification-area

On my brand new Windows 7 PC, the WiFi icon in my system tray looks funny. Here it is:

[image: wifi icon]

On my last Windows 7 PC, black lines bordered all the white bars and looked very uniform and normal. This one looks deformed/messed up.  Not cool on a brand new computer.

Thanks.

Comment: What is your "brand new Windows 7 PC"?  What resolution monitor are you running on?

Comment: Do other tray icons look as expected?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Weird. :)

From what that little pic looks like, I'd say ensure your desktop resolution is set to the native resolution/aspect ratio suggested by your monitor.

Comment: This looks like the correct answer.  On LCD screens, incorrect resolution that is too big for the natural size of the screen can definitely cause this effect where some pixels go missing.

Comment: I was using 1600x900 instead of the 1920x1080 native resolution on my 15.6" screen.  When I changed back to 1920x1080, bam, fixed.  Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The Windows 7 wireless icon is not as nice as it was in previous versions. The same question was raised [elsewhere](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_install/upgraded-from-vista-to-win7-no-colors-for-speaker/81e0358d-1434-45fc-8e17-deebaf423182), where the answer was the usual :

> This is by design in Windows 7. There
>   is no way to change this in the UI.

You could use the [Windows 7 Tray Icon Changer](http://www.technixupdate.com/change-icons-of-system-tray-items-like-action-center-volume-wifi-lan/) to give the icon some color, or a third-party widget such as [Network Meter](http://gallery.live.com/liveItemDetail.aspx?li=86656dc5-b0fe-489d-b115-44a76e050f63) to visually indicate real-time activity.

Comment: OP said it looks different from another Win7 system. He's not complaining about lack of color, he's complaining about the deformed bar widths and gaps in the border. For that matter, I'm on a Win7 system right now and it doesn't look like that.  I agree with @techie007 that it's probably a resolution or rendering issue.

Comment: @Shinrai: You may of course be right. But in case the OP cannot resolve his problem any other way, or if some installed product caused the change, this answer could maybe help him or somebody else to return the situation to normal.